# Web server using JAVA

Tags: java, restful-url

I am trying to make a server that connects to Amazon RDS instance. My code will be written in Amazon EC2 instance..
I am trying to make server that receives POST, GET requests from outer client and process it to Update, select, insert and other SQL function for Amazon RDS instance.
I do have experience of making them with node.js using express module, however, I would like to make similar server using Java, not Javascript.
Can anybody have an idea how to start?

Comment: You should take a look at [Java Servlets](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnafd.html).

Comment: This is relatively easy with [Spring Boot](https://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/), but if you don't know anything about the Spring Framework, there will be a learning curve ahead.